# Tables with prefix name and CONSTRAINT keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, constraints

I read a tutorial about [yii](/questions/tagged/yii). The tutorial supposed that I create a database called `yii_cms`. However, I decided to make its tables on a database called called `cdcol` and give all tables a prefix `yiicms_`.

So I changed `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yii_cms.file (...` ***to*** `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yiicms_file (`.

My problem with the following line:

`CONSTRAINT fk_file_user...` which it deals with two tables `file` and `user` while in my case their names are `yiicms_file` and `yiicms_user`.

My question is: How safely modify CONSTRAINT keyword to deal with the prefixed tables name?

Comment: Exactly the same as you renamed table names. Mysql has no idea it's "prefixed", it's just another table name for it.

Comment: @zerkms I realized that mysql regards every underscore is a beginning of new table name! in other words `CONSTRAINT fk_yiicms_file_yiicms_user` will make it think that there is a table called `yiicms`!

Comment: no it doesn't. `_` doesn't have any magical meaning for mysql

Comment: Hm, but PHPMyAdmin *does* treat underscores as special, doesn't it?

Comment: @Strawberry: how exactly? Even if it does - the question is about mysql, not about some 3rd party mysql managers

Comment: Not sure - haven't used it in a while :-(, but it just might account for the odd behaviour

Comment: @zerkms Indeed, I use PHPMyAdmin in doing all mysql tasks. However, I think its sql textarea acts as mysql prompt.

Comment: @zerkms See what I mean :-)

Comment: @Strawberry: it still explains **nothing**. OP didn't explain what "mysql regards every underscore is a beginning of new table name" means

Comment: @sємsєм: so what is the actual problem?

Comment: @zerkms Nothing else a mention only.

Comment: @sємsєм: nothing else to *what*? What actual issues do you experience? For the only question there the answer is: "if you rename a table - you rename it everywhere. The constraint name can be any"

Comment: I see no issue with the naming convention you are trying to use. MySQL too has most of system tables have *underscore* in their names and the database `information_schema` on its own name. Should not be an issue at all.

Comment: The point that zerkms is trying to make is that you do not need to change the constraint names, they can be anything, you do not have to have fk_yiicms_file_yiicms_user, you can just leave as fk_file_user because the name of the constraint does not matter.